# Hilight ngx-datatable rows on dblclick

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using ngx-datatable and I want to select rows on `dblclick` (used [this](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/678)). But problem is, that rows are of course not "lightened up".

Basically for activating row highlighting on click you need to add `[selectionType]="'single'"` input to `<ngx-datatable></ngx-datatable>`. Is there any way how to trigger this effect?

Comment: Will you please share code / create plnkr for this?

Comment: As it is large table integrated to project, it would be hard to make "light" example. I just need to know, if there is way how to for example use ngClass=" 'class' : id === currentRowId "

Answer (score 0):

```
(select)="onSelect($event)"
[selected]="activeRecords"
```

use above two lines of code in html template and write `onSelect()` in your typescript code as shown below

```
activeRecords  = [];
onSelect() {
    this.activeRecords = [];
    this.activeRecords.push(event.selected[0]);
}
```